# prop-menu package not showing up in emacs list-packages

Tags: emacs, package

I am trying to install the prop-menu package for emacs (on WSL2) and here's my init.el :

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("nongnu" . "https://elpa.nongnu.org/nongnu/"))
```

However, when I run the M-x package-list-packages command in the emacs GUI, I am not able to see the package listed :

[image]

Comment: Is it in either of those package archives?

Comment: Yup, it's there in both. I checked by visiting the url and searching for the package on their webpages

Comment: have you done `package-refresh-contents` _before_ doing `package-list-packages`?